# Kotlin : Differences between a function inside a class and inside a .kt file outside the class

Tags: kotlin

What is the differences between a function inside a class and inside a `.kt` file outside the class.
How to access a function in the second case inside `Operation.kt` file and how to call the function `sub()` What it is different from function `add()`.

```
class Operation {
    fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
        return x + y
    }
}

fun sub(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
   return x + y
}
```

Comment: fun sub you can access from any class just calling sub, to access fun add you must have an object of Operation class, like val op = Operation() op.add(1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

The function inside Operation class requires you to create an instance of the class before you can use it. So it could be like

`val op = Operation(this)
val result = op.add(1,1)`

but for the one outside, it can be accessed directly by just importing the class.

You can get more information here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/classes.html

*Correct me if I am wrong since I just started Kotlin.*

Comment: No correction needed!  Though worth adding that in the first case, the member function is often called a ‘method’, and operates _on_ the instance you call it on: within the function, you can refer directly to the instance's properties, and access its private methods and properties — though this artificial case doesn't have any, which is why the distinction is hard to see…